# go get can't get a module from a private repo on github

Tags: go, tags, go-modules, go-get

I have a (private) github repo with a Go module.  I've added the tag `v0.1` and github shows that tag.  I have set `go env -w GOPRIVATE=github.com/dwschulze/key-value-mod` and my ~/.gitconfig has `[url "git@github.com:"] insteadOf = https://github.com/`

But `go get` can't retrieve my module:

```
$ go get github.com/dwschulze/key-value-mod
go: github.com/dwschulze/key-value-mod upgrade => v0.0.0-20210907155619-9116b97467d6
go get: github.com/dwschulze/key-value-mod@v0.0.0-20210907155619-9116b97467d6: parsing go.mod:
        module declares its path as: key-value-mod
                but was required as: github.com/dwschulze/key-value-mod

$ go get github.com/dwschulze/key-value-mod@v0.1
go get github.com/dwschulze/key-value-mod@v0.1: no matching versions for query "v0.1"
```

What problem is `go get` having?

Comment: `go get github.com/dwschulze/key-value-mod@latest` does this work

Comment: @whitespace - No. It gives `go: github.com/dwschulze/key-value-mod latest => v0.0.0-20210907155619-9116b97467d6`.  Same as above.

Comment: are you sure you published your `git tag`? You can tag a release locally - but it may not be pushed to the remote repo.  Does the tag release appear on the github web portal? If not: `git push --tags`

Comment: Yes the tag is published.  I also published another tag 0.1 just in case there was a problem with the 'v', but it does the same thing.  I think `go get` is just broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things were causing this.  I had to clear my module cache.  The second is as Simon mentions above the module name has to be the repo URL where the module will be published.

I don't like the close coupling that go modules have with source code repositories, but that is reality.

Comment: On top of that, the `semver` format is still required. While you can `go get <pkg>@v0.1` (without a patch number), the remote git tag *MUST* have the 3-number (`vMajor.Minor.Patch`) format to work.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the error, I don't think you have any issues with the private repo. Rather, it seems to me that your `go.mod` file declares the module as

```
module key-value-mod

...
```

while it should be

```
module github.com/dwschulze/key-value-mod

...
```

Comment: Yes, it seems to be an unstated requirement that the module name has to be the repo url: https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts/c/hLkhogyFLWI.  The other thing that helped was to clear the mod cache.

Answer (score 1):

Your [go modules semver](https://golang.org/doc/modules/version-numbers) of `v0.1` is incorrect for `go modules` consumption. It includes a `major` version, `minor` version - but is missing the `patch` number:

[image: v1.4.0-beta.2]

Note: the `Pre-release Identifier` suffix here (`-beta.2`) is optional.

See also [publishing go modules](https://go.dev/blog/publishing-go-modules) docs:

> Every required module in a go.mod has a semantic version, the minimum
> version of that dependency to use to build the module.
>
> A semantic version has the form **vMAJOR.MINOR.PATCH.**

So update your tag to `v0.1.0` and it should work.

Comment: I added a v0.1.0 tag and had the same problem.